# How can I know if my rpcUrl is working or not?

Tags: web3-providers, rpc, websocket, connections

I have a 2 **rpcUrl**, I would like to pick the one that's working. How can I pick the active rpcUrl? Unfortunately, I can't catch the error log on this one.

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(rpcUrl);
```

any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

calling rpc method to check health between intervals.
Suggests `eth_chainId` as it is one of the cheapest.